# Single Child Scroll View not working for Bottom Overflowed Pixels

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

My widgets just overflowed by 18 pixels, and when I add `SingleChildScrollView()` my screen just goes blank and every widget becomes invisible.

[image: Overflow Screen]

As shown in above img my widgets are overflowed by 18 pixels.

Here is my code for that :

(Note that I have added Common card  widget in the same file, so the code may look lengthy but it's just repeated code)

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:google_fonts/google_fonts.dart';

class home extends StatefulWidget {
  const home({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _homeState createState() => _homeState();
}

class _homeState extends State<home> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.blue[900],
      resizeToAvoidBottomInset: true,
      body: Column(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
        children: <Widget>[
          SizedBox(
            height: 10.0,
          ),
          Container(
            padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                top: 55.0, left: 30.0, right: 30.0, bottom: 30.0),
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                image: DecorationImage(
              image: AssetImage('assets/Circles.png'),
              fit: BoxFit.cover,
            )),
            child: Row(
              children: [
                Column(
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Text(
                      'Control',
                      style: TextStyle(
                        color: Colors.white,
                        fontSize: 40.0,
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.w700,
                      ),
                    ),
                    Text(
                      'Panel',
                      style: TextStyle(
                        color: Colors.white,
                        fontSize: 40.0,
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.w700,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
                SizedBox(
                  width: 150,
                ),
                CircleAvatar(
                  radius: 25.0,
                )
              ],
            ),
          ),
          Expanded(
            child: Container(
              width: double.infinity,
              padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20.0),
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                color: Colors.white,
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                  topLeft: Radius.circular(35.0),
                  topRight: Radius.circular(35.0),
                ),
              ),
              child: Column(
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                children: [
                  SizedBox(
                    height: 30.0,
                  ),
                  Text(
                    'All Rooms',
                    style: GoogleFonts.mPlusRounded1c(
                        fontSize: 20.0,
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                        color: Colors.blue[900]),
                  ),
                  SizedBox(
                    height: 20.0,
                  ),
                  Column(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                    children: [
                      Row(
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                        children: [
                          Column(
                            children: [
                              Card(
                                elevation: 10.0,
                                shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20.0),
                                ),
                                child: Padding(
                                  padding: EdgeInsets.all(25.0),
                                  child: Column(
                                    crossAxisAlignment:
                                        CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                                    children: [
                                      Image(
                                        image: AssetImage('assets/bed.png'),
                                      ),
                                      SizedBox(
                                        height: 15.0,
                                      ),
                                      Text(
                                        'Bed Room   ',
                                        style: GoogleFonts.mPlusRounded1c(
                                            fontSize: 20.0,
                                            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                            color: Colors.black),
                                      ),
                                      Text(
                                        '4 Lights',
                                        style: GoogleFonts.mPlusRounded1c(
                                            fontSize: 15.0,
                                            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                            color: Colors.yellow[700]),
                                      ),
                                    ],
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ),
                            ],
                          ),
                          Card(
                            elevation: 10.0,
                            shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20.0),
                            ),
                            child: Padding(
                              padding: EdgeInsets.all(25.0),
                              child: Column(
                                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                                children: [
                                  Image(
                                    image: AssetImage('assets/room.png'),
                                  ),
                                  SizedBox(
                                    height: 15.0,
                                  ),
                                  Text(
                                    'Living Room',
                                    style: GoogleFonts.mPlusRounded1c(
                                        fontSize: 20.0,
                                        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                        color: Colors.black),
                                  ),
                                  Text(
                                    '2 Lights',
                                    style: GoogleFonts.mPlusRounded1c(
                                        fontSize: 15.0,
                                        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                        color: Colors.yellow[700]),
                                  ),
                                ],
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                      Row(
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                        children: [
                          Column(
                            children: [
                              Card(
                                elevation: 10.0,
                                shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20.0),
                                ),
                                child: Padding(
                                  padding: EdgeInsets.all(25.0),
                                  child: Column(
                                    crossAxisAlignment:
                                        CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                                    children: [
                                      Image(
                                        image: AssetImage('assets/kitchen.png'),
                                      ),
                                      SizedBox(
                                        height: 15.0,
                                      ),
                                      Text(
                                        'Kitchen      ',
                                        style: GoogleFonts.mPlusRounded1c(
                                            fontSize: 20.0,
                                            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                            color: Colors.black),
                                      ),
                                      Text(
                                        '5 Lights',
                                        style: GoogleFonts.mPlusRounded1c(
                                            fontSize: 15.0,
                                            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                            color: Colors.yellow[700]),
                                      ),
                                    ],
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ),
                            ],
                          ),
                          Card(
                            elevation: 10.0,
                            shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20.0),
                            ),
                            child: Padding(
                              padding: EdgeInsets.all(25.0),
                              child: Column(
                                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                                children: [
                                  Image(
                                    image: AssetImage('assets/bathtube.png'),
                                  ),
                                  SizedBox(
                                    height: 15.0,
                                  ),
                                  Text(
                                    'Bath Room  ',
                                    style: GoogleFonts.mPlusRounded1c(
                                        fontSize: 20.0,
                                        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                        color: Colors.black),
                                  ),
                                  Text(
                                    '1 Light',
                                    style: GoogleFonts.mPlusRounded1c(
                                        fontSize: 15.0,
                                        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                        color: Colors.yellow[700]),
                                  ),
                                ],
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                      Row(
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                        children: [
                          Column(
                            children: [
                              Card(
                                elevation: 10.0,
                                shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20.0),
                                ),
                                child: Padding(
                                  padding: EdgeInsets.all(25.0),
                                  child: Column(
                                    crossAxisAlignment:
                                        CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                                    children: [
                                      Image(
                                        image: AssetImage('assets/house.png'),
                                      ),
                                      SizedBox(
                                        height: 15.0,
                                      ),
                                      Text(
                                        'Outdoor     ',
                                        style: GoogleFonts.mPlusRounded1c(
                                            fontSize: 20.0,
                                            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                            color: Colors.black),
                                      ),
                                      Text(
                                        '5 Lights',
                                        style: GoogleFonts.mPlusRounded1c(
                                            fontSize: 15.0,
                                            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                            color: Colors.yellow[700]),
                                      ),
                                    ],
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ),
                            ],
                          ),
                          Card(
                            elevation: 10.0,
                            shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20.0),
                            ),
                            child: Padding(
                              padding: EdgeInsets.all(25.0),
                              child: Column(
                                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                                children: [
                                  Image(
                                    image: AssetImage('assets/balcony.png'),
                                  ),
                                  SizedBox(
                                    height: 15.0,
                                  ),
                                  Text(
                                    'Balcony      ',
                                    style: GoogleFonts.mPlusRounded1c(
                                        fontSize: 20.0,
                                        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                        color: Colors.black),
                                  ),
                                  Text(
                                    '2 Lights',
                                    style: GoogleFonts.mPlusRounded1c(
                                        fontSize: 15.0,
                                        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                        color: Colors.yellow[700]),
                                  ),
                                ],
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ],
                  )
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
          Text('Bottom nav bar')
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

And when I wrap the widget with `SingleChildScrollView()` my screen goes blank as shown below:

[image: Error after using widget]

Can anyone tell why it's happening and how can I resolve this?

Any help will be much appreciated :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try below code hope its helpful to you, Wrap your Column inside **SingleChildScrollView** refer documentaion [here](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/SingleChildScrollView-class.html),
Just change my icons with your images

```
Scaffold(
  backgroundColor: Colors.blue[900],
  resizeToAvoidBottomInset: true,
  body: Column(
    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
    children: <Widget>[
      SizedBox(
        height: 10.0,
      ),
      Container(
        padding: EdgeInsets.only(
            top: 55.0, left: 30.0, right: 30.0, bottom: 30.0),
        child: Row(
          children: [
            Column(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
              children: <Widget>[
                Text(
                  'Control',
                  style: TextStyle(
                    color: Colors.white,
                    fontSize: 40.0,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.w700,
                  ),
                ),
                Text(
                  'Panel',
                  style: TextStyle(
                    color: Colors.white,
                    fontSize: 40.0,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.w700,
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
            SizedBox(
              width: 150,
            ),
            CircleAvatar(
              radius: 25.0,
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
      Expanded(
        child: Container(
          width: double.infinity,
          padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20.0),
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            color: Colors.white,
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
              topLeft: Radius.circular(35.0),
              topRight: Radius.circular(35.0),
            ),
          ),
          child: SingleChildScrollView(//Your SingleChildScrollView Widget
            child: Column(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
              children: [
                SizedBox(
                  height: 30.0,
                ),
                Text(
                  'All Rooms',
                ),
                SizedBox(
                  height: 20.0,
                ),
                Column(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                  children: [
                    Row(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                      children: [
                        Column(
                          children: [
                            Card(
                              elevation: 10.0,
                              shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20.0),
                              ),
                              child: Padding(
                                padding: EdgeInsets.all(25.0),
                                child: Column(
                                  crossAxisAlignment:
                                      CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                                  children: [
                                    Icon(Icons.add),
                                    SizedBox(
                                      height: 15.0,
                                    ),
                                    Text(
                                      'Bed Room   ',
                                    ),
                                    Text(
                                      '4 Lights',
                                    ),
                                  ],
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                        Card(
                          elevation: 10.0,
                          shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20.0),
                          ),
                          child: Padding(
                            padding: EdgeInsets.all(25.0),
                            child: Column(
                              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                              children: [
                                Icon(Icons.add),
                                SizedBox(
                                  height: 15.0,
                                ),
                                Text(
                                  'Living Room',
                                ),
                                Text(
                                  '2 Lights',
                                ),
                              ],
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                    Row(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                      children: [
                        Column(
                          children: [
                            Card(
                              elevation: 10.0,
                              shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20.0),
                              ),
                              child: Padding(
                                padding: EdgeInsets.all(25.0),
                                child: Column(
                                  crossAxisAlignment:
                                      CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                                  children: [
                                    Icon(Icons.add),
                                    SizedBox(
                                      height: 15.0,
                                    ),
                                    Text(
                                      'Kitchen      ',
                                    ),
                                    Text(
                                      '5 Lights',
                                    ),
                                  ],
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                        Card(
                          elevation: 10.0,
                          shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20.0),
                          ),
                          child: Padding(
                            padding: EdgeInsets.all(25.0),
                            child: Column(
                              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                              children: [
                                Icon(Icons.add),
                                SizedBox(
                                  height: 15.0,
                                ),
                                Text(
                                  'Bath Room  ',
                                ),
                                Text(
                                  '1 Light',
                                ),
                              ],
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                    Row(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                      children: [
                        Column(
                          children: [
                            Card(
                              elevation: 10.0,
                              shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20.0),
                              ),
                              child: Padding(
                                padding: EdgeInsets.all(25.0),
                                child: Column(
                                  crossAxisAlignment:
                                      CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                                  children: [
                                    Icon(Icons.add),
                                    SizedBox(
                                      height: 15.0,
                                    ),
                                    Text(
                                      'Kitchen      ',
                                    ),
                                    Text(
                                      '5 Lights',
                                    ),
                                  ],
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                        Card(
                          elevation: 10.0,
                          shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20.0),
                          ),
                          child: Padding(
                            padding: EdgeInsets.all(25.0),
                            child: Column(
                              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                              children: [
                                Icon(Icons.add),
                                SizedBox(
                                  height: 15.0,
                                ),
                                Text(
                                  'Bath Room  ',
                                ),
                                Text(
                                  '1 Light',
                                ),
                              ],
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                    Row(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                      children: [
                        Column(
                          children: [
                            Card(
                              elevation: 10.0,
                              shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20.0),
                              ),
                              child: Padding(
                                padding: EdgeInsets.all(25.0),
                                child: Column(
                                  crossAxisAlignment:
                                      CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                                  children: [
                                    Icon(Icons.add),
                                    SizedBox(
                                      height: 15.0,
                                    ),
                                    Text(
                                      'Kitchen      ',
                                    ),
                                    Text(
                                      '5 Lights',
                                    ),
                                  ],
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                        Card(
                          elevation: 10.0,
                          shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20.0),
                          ),
                          child: Padding(
                            padding: EdgeInsets.all(25.0),
                            child: Column(
                              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                              children: [
                                Icon(Icons.add),
                                SizedBox(
                                  height: 15.0,
                                ),
                                Text(
                                  'Bath Room  ',
                                ),
                                Text(
                                  '1 Light',
                                ),
                              ],
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                    Row(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                      children: [
                        Column(
                          children: [
                            Card(
                              elevation: 10.0,
                              shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20.0),
                              ),
                              child: Padding(
                                padding: EdgeInsets.all(25.0),
                                child: Column(
                                  crossAxisAlignment:
                                      CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                                  children: [
                                    Icon(Icons.add),
                                    SizedBox(
                                      height: 15.0,
                                    ),
                                    Text(
                                      'Outdoor     ',
                                    ),
                                    Text(
                                      '5 Lights',
                                    ),
                                  ],
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                        Card(
                          elevation: 10.0,
                          shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20.0),
                          ),
                          child: Padding(
                            padding: EdgeInsets.all(25.0),
                            child: Column(
                              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                              children: [
                                Icon(Icons.add),
                                SizedBox(
                                  height: 15.0,
                                ),
                                Text(
                                  'Balcony      ',
                                ),
                                Text(
                                  '2 Lights',
                                ),
                              ],
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ],
                )
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
      Text('Bottom nav bar')
    ],
  ),
);
```

Your Result Screen look like -> [image]

Comment: Thanx! it worked :)